# Laravel / October : multidimensional array mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays, laravel

I'm starting on Laravel and I have a problem with MySQL result :

My request is simple `$query = DB::select('select * from my_table ');`

In my table I have columns (id, title, id_group) where id_group correspond to an other table

And I want to display all components for each id_group in different div

I tried this code to gather all id_group in différents arrays

```
foreach($query as $tab){

    $array[] = array($tab->id_group => array(
                           'id' => $tab->id,
                           'id_group' => $tab->id_group,
                           'title' => $tab->title
                    ));

}
```

Then I want to display each group in Octobercms (twig)

```
{% for tab in array %}

    {% for tab2 in tab %}
        {{ tab2.group_id }} - {{ tab2.title }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

But it doesn't work ...

Comment: And your code isn't working?

Comment: No, when I display the array with two loop for, the result isn't what I want ...

Comment: Then please update your question with the result you're getting and the one you want.

Comment: try var_dump() or dd() to see what it's returning, might help you to figure out where you're going wrong as you'll see the array contents

Answer (score 0):

I don't know twig exactly how to do in twig, but what is happening is that the data being passed to the view is probably:

```
[
...,
    [ {id_group => ["id" =>...]} ],
...
]
```

And you are trying to parse it as if it was:

```
[
...,
    [ ["id" =>...] ],
...
]
```

If you don't want to change your view, change your foreach to:

```
foreach($query as $tab){

    $array[] = array(
                   array
                       'id' => $tab->id,
                       'id_group' => $tab->id_group,
                       'title' => $tab->title
                    )
                );
}
```